# Leave out code in release version

Tags: c#, .net, dll, smartinspect

I am using smartinspect in a .net library I have made to track methods, etc. But for a release configuration I want to avoid the deployment of smartinspect and the overhead of tracking everything inside code. Is there an easy way to achieve this without using compiler directives each time I call a method?

Example code:

```
    public bool OpenDocument(string srcFile)
    {
        SiExportWordSession.EnterMethod(this, "OpenDocument");
        try
        {
            SiExportWordSession.LogString("srcFile", srcFile);

            try
            {
                _doc = new Document(srcFile);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SiExportWordSession.LogException(e);
                ErrorName = e.GetType().Name;
                ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            SiExportWordSession.LeaveMethod(this, "OpenDocument");
        }
    }
```

My first idea was create a wrapper for smartinspect which either calls smartinspect or does nothing, depending on release configuration. But this wouldn´t get me rid of the try finally constructs. Are there better methods to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [Conditional Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099.aspx). I short: you can use ```#if DEBUG```. See [this post for an example](http://rickvandenbosch.net/blog/is-my-c-application-running-in-debug-mode-or-about-pre-processor-directives/)

Comment: That would require every call to be enclosed by an `#if`. @RickvandenBosch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way, but it still requires you to map the methods you are using.

What the key is to this is adding a `Conditional` attribute to your methods that will indicate on what build it will run:

```
[Conditional("TRACE")]
```

All code invoking that method will only be compiled into the code when the build defines the `TRACE` constant.